# Viewing all accessible drives in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I noticed that cd \ navigates to the root of my drive.

But there are other drives that I can access on my computer.

Is there a command in PowerShell that lists all of the drives that I can connect to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This somewhat depends on what you're calling a "drive". In PowerShell, there are drives that represent your usual local or network-mapped volumes, as well as drives which hold other objects like Aliases, Environment Variables, Functions, PowerShell Variables, Registry Hives, and more.

To see a list of all "drives" in PowerShell, use:

```
Get-PSDrive
```

Or you can use the built-in alias:

```
gdr
```

(Anywhere you see `Get-PSDrive` below, you may substitute `gdr` instead.)

To get only FileSystem drives, e.g.: local or network-mapped volumes or media bays, use:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

To get *just* local drives, or *just* hard drives, I couldn't find an appropriate Property or Method in the objects output by `Get-PSDrive` to filter by. A little Googling later, I found [Microsoft's Get-PSDrive documentation on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849796.aspx). There, along with details of how to use `Get-PSDrive`, a few other PowerShell-accessible methods of drive enumeration are also listed. One I found useful is via the System.IO.DriveInfo class in the .NET Framework.

The below command, executable via PowerShell, will list only local hard drives.

```
[System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed'}
```

If you want to include any local drive - not just hard drives - use this:

```
[System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 'Network'}
```

If you want to only see drive letters, pipe the output to `Select-Object`, like this:

```
[System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 'Network'} | Select-Object -Property Name
```

Note that `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` also have built-in aliases of `?` and `select, respectively. (`Where-Object`is also usable as`where` - it's just really a matter of preference.) The System.IO.DriveInfo class can also be shortened to just IO.DriveInfo. So, that last command could be run as this, if you like:

```
[IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | ? {$_.DriveType -ne 'Network} | select -Property Name
```

Of course, there's plenty else you can do with `Get-PSDrives`, and the .NET classes accessible via PowerShell, as well as many other PowerShell shortcuts available. I suggest reading up more on TechNet and similar sites, and using the `Get-Help` and `Get-Command` cmdlets to gain better familiarity with the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command in `powershell` to list all drives on your PC

```
gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

or

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```